# Update in MongoDB multiple values in array

Tags: php, mongodb

I try to add some values in existing Collection using Update but I retrieve just just the last value:

An example:

When I try to add to this document in MongoDB an array with different values like this:

```
   $test=
array("one"=>"Item1","two"=>"Item2","three"=>"Item3","four"=>"Item4",
  "five"=>"Item5","six"=>"Item6");

  $collectionMeasurements->insert($test);
  for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
   $collectionMeasurements->update(
         array("one" => "Item1"),
         array('$set' => array('new' => $i)),
         array("multiple" => true)
  );

  }
```

I get as results:

```
Array
 (
 [_id] => MongoId Object
    (
    )

[five] => Item5
[four] => Item4
[new] => 4
[one] => Item1
[six] => Item6
[three] => Item3
[two] => Item2
 )
```

I would like to get something like that:

```
Array
  (
   [_id] => MongoId Object
    (
    )

[five] => Item5
[four] => Item4
[new] => array(1,2,3,4)
[one] => Item1
[six] => Item6
[three] => Item3
[two] => Item2
 )
```

Any suggestion of how I can accomplish this please?
Thanks!!!

Comment: post your mongo output as a normal json, not a php print_r()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem. YOu overwrite the value for a key `new` in each iteration of your script.

What you have to do is the following

```
$arr = array()
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
   arr[$i] = $i; // or initialize array in a normal way
}

$collectionMeasurements->update(
   array("one" => "Item1"),
   array('$set' => array('new' => $arr)),
   array("multiple" => true)
);
```